# Add a set of 'sub-forms' (probably form set) to a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-orm, modelform, formset

I'm making some progress in solving this. What I want to model is this:

I have a model for materials, a model for projects, and an intermediary model to specify more data to the many-to-many relationship between them. The objective is to allow a project not only to have multiple materials but also to specify a quantity for each.

These are my models:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3000, blank=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='materials')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} (${self.price}/{self.unit})'


class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3000, blank=True)
    materials = models.ManyToManyField(to=Material, through='ProjectMaterialSet', related_name='projects')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class ProjectMaterialSet(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(to=Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material = models.ForeignKey(to=Material, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material_qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

Now, I have successfully rendered the project form containing a checkbox list of the materials (without the quantity feature), another form listing just one material as a checkbox, and a field for the quantity (a form of the ProjectMaterialSet model).

[image]

[image]

Now, the part I'm struggling with is how to combine both. So far, I think what I need to do is have a query set of the available materials in the ProjectForm, to then add to it a series of sub-forms (here is where I think I should use formsets, however, I'm unsure how) that passes each material pk so I can render each form as a ModelMultipleChoiceField so I get to use the checkbox widget for each material.

My natural instinct as someone not related with formsets is to for-loop over the materials and create form instances that save to a dict or something around those lines. However, I read on the Django forum a good phrase about using Django features instead of hacking a solution, and I do feel the formsets can be used for this, I'm just unsure how.

Clarification: I need to pass each material pk to the ProjectMaterialSetForm so I can get the checkbox for each material (as I'm getting a query set with just one result since I'm filtering by pk), and link a quantity input to that single checkbox.

I feel I have most of it done, I'm just not sure how to add the sub-forms, and if someone could also help about the custom save and validation required, that'd be amazing!

Here are my forms:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('name', 'description')

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter the project name'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter the project description', 'rows': '5'})
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Store the user object and materials QuerySet
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user') if 'user' in kwargs else None
        self.materials = Material.objects.filter(created_by=self.user) if self.user is not None else None # This is a QuerySet

        # Call parent __init__ method, which we are modifying
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Somehow create a set of forms, one for each material
            # Perhaps using formsets is the ideal solution, however, I keep finding
            # myself going to the route of a dict with forms and adding them as I
            # iterate over the materials query set. 

            # Since formsets are a thing, I'm pretty sure I can somehow create a batch
            # of forms (probably the extra argument is the key here), to then somehow
            # add the material_id to each of them.


class ProjectMaterialSetForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectMaterialSet
        fields = ('material', 'material_qty')

        material = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None)
        
        widgets = {
            'material': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-check-input'}),
            'material_qty': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        material_id = kwargs.pop('material_id') if 'material_id' in kwargs else None
        super(ProjectMaterialSetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['materials'].queryset = Material.objects.filter(pk=material_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come into a similar situation, and I ended up with customizing model formset.

```
class ProjectMaterialSetFormSet(forms.BaseModelFormSet):
    # some required / optional attributes
    extra = 0
    can_delete = True
    can_order = False
    max_num = 1000
    validate_max = False
    # If you want to enforce each project to have at least
    # one material, set validate_min to True
    min_num = 1
    validate_min = False
    absolute_max = 1000
    can_delete_extra = True
    renderer = forms.renderers.get_default_renderer()

    model = ProjectMaterialSet
    class ProjectMaterialSetForm(forms.ModelForm):
        # Add an extra name field to help form rendering
        material_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
        class Meta:
            model = ProjectMaterialSet
            fields = ['material', 'material_qty']
    form = ProjectMaterialSetForm

    # ProjectForm is like another management form for the formset: 
    # rendered, validated and saved together with formset. 
    class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Project
            fields = ['name', 'description']

    @cached_property
    def project_form(self):
        if self.is_bound:
            form = self.ProjectForm(self.data, self.files, prefix=self.prefix)
            form.full_clean()
        else:
            form = self.ProjectForm(prefix=self.prefix)
        return form

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if not self.project_form.is_valid():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Project form invalid')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        project = self.project_form.save(commit=commit)
        for form in self:
            form.instance.project = project
        return super(ProjectMaterialSetFormSet, self).save(commit=commit)
        # return project if you want the instance for further operation,
        # but just don't forget to call super().save()

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Override get_queryset to return none if not specified. 
        # Otherwise, it just returns all. 
        if not hasattr(self, '_queryset'):
            if self.queryset is not None:
                qs = self.queryset
            else:
                qs = self.model.objects.none()
            if not qs.ordered:
                qs = qs.order_by(self.model._meta.pk.name)
            self._queryset = qs
        return self._queryset
```

When rendering the formset, provide all materials as initial data

```
def project_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ProjectMaterialSetFormSet(request.POST, prefix='proj-mats')
        if formset.is_valid():
            proj_mat_set = formset.save()
    else:
        initial = Material.objects.values(material=F('id'), material_name=F('name')).annotate(DELETE=Value(True))
        # Don’t forget to set prefix same as above. 
        #formset = ProjectMaterialSetFormSet(initial=initial)
        formset = ProjectMaterialSetFormSet(initial=initial, prefix='proj-mats')
        # Not so sure about why minus 1 here. I did it 
        # in my code. Remove it if you find problem. 
        formset.extra = len(initial) - 1
    context = {'formset': formset}
    return render(request, 'path/to/template.html', context)
```

When rendering the template, don't forget to render project_form. If you tend to render each child form separately, which is recommended here, also don't forget to render management form.

```
{{ formset.project_form }}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ form.prefix }}-DELETE" {{ form.DELETE.value|yesno:',checked' }} id="id-{{ form.prefix }}-DELETE">
<input type="hidden" name="{{ form.prefix }}-material" value="{{ form.material.value }}">
<input type="hidden" name="{{ form.prefix }}-material_name" value="{{ form.material_name.value }}">
<label for="id-{{ form.prefix }}-DELETE">{{ form.material_name.value }}</label>
<input type="text" name="{{ form.prefix }}-material_qty" value="{{ form.material_qty.value }}" pattern="\d+">
{% endfor %}
```

--- Update ---

The idea comes from [ManagementForm of Django's Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform), which contains two meta fields: `{prefix}-TOTAL_FORMS` and `{prefix}-INITIAL_FORMS`.

This looks very similar in your case: a formset for `ProjectMaterialSet`, and a form for `Project` that tightly related to the formset.

Then what to do next is to mimic how Django handles management_form, which can be found in [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/formsets.py#L147):

The `management_form`, as a @cached_property method to formset, will create a `ManagementForm` instance when accessed. This form will get validated when you call `.is_valid` on formset, which accesses formset.errors, which then triggers formset.full_clean, which then triggers management_form.is_valid.

In your case, the clean route can be simplified by putting the project_form.is_valid into formset.clean.

Next question is how to create such formset class, and instantiate an instance in the view function.

Django has a shortcut `modelformset_factory` to help us create ModelFormSet. If you look into its [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/models.py#L1008), it is nothing more of defining an object that inherits from `BaseModelFormSet` class, with some controlling attributes (extra, can_delete, can_order, etc).

The you can totally define a child `ModelFormSet` class, setup all those attributes as if you were calling `modelformset_factory`, override `clean` method to include validation on `ProjectForm`, and override `save` method to save the `project` first, and then to save `ProjectMaterialSet` with project attribute set to the newly created `project`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I'm testing the code right now, could you explain the .annotate(DELETE... part? I had to remove it as it was causing some errors. Also, can you point me to where you found the info to come up with the solution? I'm rather new to Django and would love to learn what each part of the code does as well as the thought process to arrive a this solution

Comment: Sure, I will update my answer a little bit later. The `.annotate(DELETE..)` part is used to denote if the instance should be deleted. If it is an existing instance, then it will be deleted from the database. Otherwise, it will tell the formset to not validate that single form.

Comment: Sorry, .annotate(DELETE should be `.annotate(DELETE=Value(True))`. I didn't know I did not finish that line. I have now correct it. This will make all materials unchecked by default. And in the DELETE input checkbox in the template part, I have also mistaken the `yesno` template filter. Should be checked when DELETE is false.

Comment: Thanks for the help again!

I'm implementing the solution right now, however, the form validation seems to be failing, this is the POST content: (see in next comment)

Comment: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['...'], 'form-name': ['Sample'], 'form-description': ['Sample.'], 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['3'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['1'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'form-0-material': ['4'], 'form-0-material_name': ['Web Developer (Hourly)'], 'form-0-DELETE': ['on'], 'form-0-material_qty': ['10'], 'form-1-material': ['5'], 'form-1-material_name': ['Designer (Hourly)'], 'form-1-DELETE': ['on'], 'form-1-material_qty': ['2'], 'form-2-material': ['6'], 'form-2-material_name': ['Project Manager (Hourly)'], 'form-2-material_qty': ['1']}>

Comment: After some digging, I found the ProjectForm is failing to validate, the error:

 `project_form = ProjectMaterialSetFormSet.ProjectForm(request.POST, prefix='proj-mats')

        if not project_form.is_valid():
             print('Project Form Errors:', project_form.errors) # Project Form Errors: <ul class="errorlist"><li>name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

It seems the project name is failing to validate, and the template renders the project name with the `name` attribute set to 'form-name', unsure if this is the error?

Comment: I notice you set `prefix` to `proj-mats`, but in the `POST` QueryDict, the prefix is `form`. I apologize again that in my answer I forget to add the prefix when initializing the formset. Since the form error complains about not finding a value for Project.name. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Man, I cannot thank you enough! It's working now! I had to fix one extra thing, I forgot to mention I have a created_by field on the project model that I populate to the current logged-in user. I modified a bit the save() method to pass in the user object and that did the trick. I'll study all the stuff to linked to on the answer to better understand it. How can we connect? I literally shouted a "YESSSS" right now hahaha

Comment: My pleasure. I just did what any other SOer will do. If you have further questions, leave a comment here and I will see.